# Twice repetition in run()

Tags: android, runnable

I expect that the following code block writes "Hello!" once per second. But it writes it twice. What am I doing wrong?

```
    handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.d("message", "Hello!");             
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
    runOnUiThread(r);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it writes it twice because you are posting it twice in the UI thread queue. One with the handler, the other with the runnable.

```
handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
runOnUiThread(r);
```

Accordingly with your requirements get rid of one the two. To me it looks like you want just the `handler`

Answer (score 1):

Do a simple implementation, create a `TimerTask`

```
Timer timer = new Timer ();
timer.schedule (new TimerTask () {
            @Override
            public void run () {
               // Print your Hello here...
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
```